# Programatically check if a commit updates a submodule

Tags: git

Is there an easy way to use Git plumbing to programatically check if a submodule was updated in some commit (e.g., HEAD).  (You don't care which one, you just want to know that A submodule changed)

Comment: I see a close vote for the reason " Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" but I don't understand why... is this the case here? The question seems legit to me.

Comment: Prior to filing this question, I read through the entire manpage of git-diff-tree and did not see anything that looked relevant to solving this. At the moment, the only "correct" way I can think of doing this is, retrieve all paths of submodules before and after, and then check if a diff changed any of those paths. Blegh.

Answer (score 3):

To check a commit's changes against its parents with core commands, use

```
git diff-tree -m -r $commit     # all parents
git diff-tree -r $commit{~,}    # first parent
```

Submodule entries have type 16,

```
git diff-tree -m -r $commit | awk '$1":"$2~/:16/'
```

will print all changed submodule entries in $commit.

(edit: had `-c` option on there by mistake, that shows only conflict resolutions, not what was wanted).
(edit 2: gaak! Submodule type is 16, not 04. "I knew that". Also, to compare against all parents, use `-m`)

Comment: Ooh, I didn't see the type field in the output. That looks very good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of a built-in way, but this does the job:

```
git diff $COMMIT~ $COMMIT | grep -qE '^(-|\+)Subproject commit'
echo $?
# Return code 0 if commit contains changes to a subproject
# Return code 1 if commit contains no changes to a subproject
```

Comment: This will spuriously flag commits that contain "Subproject" somewhere in their diff text.

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang yes, but you can grep for `'^Subproject'` to restrict the match to the start of the line—since context diffs add space, `+`, or `-`, that should do the job.

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang I updated the regex. Could you please tell us what you **don't** want to match? Is it a reasonable concern to match regular diffs containing `Subproject` in the beginning?